# API VK не отправляет сообщение из группы

Tags: php, vkontakte-api, вконтакте, callback

Имеется вот такой скрипт:

```html
    <?php 

if (!isset($_REQUEST)) { 
  return; 
} 

//Строка для подтверждения адреса сервера из настроек Callback API 
$confirmation_token = '55555'; 

//Ключ доступа сообщества 
$token = 'aba3128c2'; 

//Получаем и декодируем уведомление 
$data = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input')); 
//Проверяем, что находится в поле "type" 
switch ($data->type) { 
  //Если это уведомление для подтверждения адреса сервера... 
  case 'confirmation': 
    //...отправляем строку для подтверждения адреса 
    echo $confirmation_token; 
    break; 

//Если это уведомление о новом сообщении... 
  case 'message_new': 
    //...получаем id его автора 
    $user_id = $data->object->user_id; 
    //затем с помощью users.get получаем данные об авторе 
    $user_info = json_decode(file_get_contents("https://api.vk.com/method/users.get?user_ids={$user_id}&v=5.0")); 

//и извлекаем из ответа его имя 
    $user_name = $user_info->response[0]->first_name; 
    $last_name = $user_info->response[0]->last_name; 

    //Получаем текст сообщения
    $body = $data->object->body;
    //Массив с ответами
    $otv = array('Привет' =>'Привет' , 'Как дела?' =>'Нормально');
    //Генерируем ответное сообщение, путем обращения к массиву с ответами
    $message = $otv['$body'];


    $request_params = array( 
      'message' => $message, 
      'user_id' => $user_id, 
      'access_token' => $token, 
      'v' => '5.0' 
    ); 
    $get_params = http_build_query($request_params); 


file_get_contents('https://api.vk.com/method/messages.send?'. $get_params); 

//Возвращаем "ok" серверу Callback API 
    echo('ok'); 

break; 
} 
?>
```

Но когда я пишу сообщение в группу свою в ВК с текстом "Привет" — в ответ мне ничего не приходит. Если, допустим, изменить

```
$message = $otv['$body'];
```

на

```
$message = "Вы прислали сообщение: $body ";
```

то я получаю ответ с моим отправленным сообщением. В чём может быть проблема?

Answer (score 1):

В строке $message = $otv['$body'];  убери у $body кавычки )) у меня сработало

Answer (score 0):

api vk вам скажет что неправильно в вашем запросе, но для этого нужно прочитать ответ. по вашему страшному коду можно сделать так:

```
file_get_contents('https://api.vk.com/method/messages.send?'. $get_params, $api_response);
var_dump($api_response);
```